# Failed at step CHDIR spawning "/usr/bin/dotnet": No such file or directory

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, deployment

I tried to deploy the ASP.NET Core 2 website to Ubuntu following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x.

However, it throws an exception:

```
Failed at step CHDIR spawning "/usr/bin/dotnet": No such file or directory from the file
```

The error is from this file

```
 [Unit]
 Description=Example .NET Web API App running on Ubuntu

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/aspnetcore/hellomvc
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/aspnetcore/hellomvc/hellomvc.dll
Restart=always
RestartSec=10  # Restart service after 10 seconds if dotnet service crashes
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-example
User=www-data
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

However, the command /usr/bin/dotnet exists, and it's fine when I ran

```
/usr/bin/dotnet /var/aspnetcore/hellomvc/hellomvc.dll
```

I googled it, but the best answer I found suggested it's related to the user www-data. Still I could not figure out what's wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ensure that user `www-data` has read permissions for `/var/aspnetcore/hellomvc`?

Comment: @Evk. thank you! Seems this is the issue. After www-data has been granted the permission, it worked!

Answer (score 33):

Look at for the WorkingDirectory path, cd to the path directly. 
In my case, WorkingDirectory path folder was missing and when I created it manually it started working.

Hope this help.

Comment: And don't forget to `daemon-reload` after editing.

Answer (score -4):

Install dotnet core

```
wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > microsoft.asc.gpg
sudo mv microsoft.asc.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/
wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list
sudo mv prod.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list
sudo chown root:root /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.asc.gpg
sudo chown root:root /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.1
```

sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/api.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Api

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/media/data/Services/Api
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /media/data/Services/Api/Api.dll --sever.urls=http://*:7034
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=Api
User=www-data
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false
TimeoutStopSec=90

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

RUN these commands after creating the file

```
systemd-escape "<value-to-escape>"
sudo systemctl enable api.service
sudo systemctl start api.service
sudo systemctl status api.service
```

NB
always verify the location of the files and folders